# convert organic chemistry latex into its english description

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the Latex of benzene suppose. and from this I have to write a python code to convert the same latex into its english description.
example : the latex of benzene is `\chemfig{C*6((-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=)}`
then by using a python code how could I write it in its description ie the shown fig of the latex is a 6 side polygon with alternate double bonds called a benzene ring

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking as this is a LaTeX site and not a python one. If there are standard python tools to do this then perhaps you could use pythontex? If this is really a question about python then it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you required to write the conversion in Python? If yes, why? If other solutions are also ok, would that include a conversion in LaTeX itself? It would be rather difficult in either case, but maybe you can use some of the `chemfig` internals to get some hints on what kinds of structures are being drawn.